# why enum needs to cast to int while comparing with integer value in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, enums

For example, I have declared the following `enum` in C#.

C# code:

```
public enum LobMaster :int 
{
    RetailBroking = 1,
    HNI = 2,
    TechnologyInfrastructure = 3,
}
```

cshtml code:

```
@int code = 2
@if (LobMaster.RetailBroking == code)
{

}
```

If I try to compare int enum with integer value it gives me following error message.

> operator '==' cannot be applied to types 'LobMaster' and 'int'

While my enum

> LobMaster

is already an int type.

But when I cast the enum to int and then compare with int value it works fine.
So my question is why I need to cast enum to int as enum is already an int.

Comment: _"While my enum is already an int type"_ - incorrrect.  This isn't c/c++

Comment: An `enum` is not an `int`, its just that its underlying type is `int`

Comment: From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/enum) - _The underlying type specifies how much storage is allocated for each enumerator. However, an explicit cast is necessary to convert from enum type to an integral type_

Answer (score 5):

The main purpose of Enums is to remove "magic numbers", so you should ask yourself - why do you want to use those magic numbers?

Much better comparison would be:

```
Session["Lob_code"] is LobMaster && LobMaster.MassAffluent == (LobMaster)Session["Lob_code"]
```

This way you are avoiding those magic numbers and your code just provides all the context.

Answer (score 0):

```
@if ((int) LobMaster.MassAffluent == Convert.ToInt32(Session["Lob_code"])) { }
```

you should be able to cast the left hand value and then do the conoarison